# Apple mail inboxes take a very long time to load

Tags: apple-mail

Does anyone know why my Apple mail inboxes are taking an extremely long time to load? In other words, sometimes it takes up to 4 minutes for unread messages in a folder to display when I click on that folder. Is this an indexing issue, or something else?

Not sure if this is relevant to situation, but Spotlight begins reindexing my entire drive every single time I reboot. The entire drive - for hours, and this is slowing everything down. I have tried turning spotlight on and off - nothing works...

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out. It is Mavericks slowing it down.

Comment: Can you please give use a more detailed description of how you figured this out? if possible. thanks.

Comment: Yes, I learned bout it here: http://www.macrumors.com/2013/10/31/apple-working-on-fix-for-os-x-mavericks-mail-app-issues/

Comment: put the solution in your answer, instead of a link, that way it may help someone in the future even if the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

It might be spotlight-related, as you mentioned.  Assuming your mail accounts are IMAP, then one thing to try is to quit Mail.  In your ~/Library/Mail/ folder, there is a file "**Envelope Index**".  Move that file to a safe place (like, your Desktop), and restart mail.  You will probably see a "welcome" screen, and then Mail will go through your messages.  After the main Mail window finally appears, it might be slow for a while, as Spotlight will again re-index the messages; but, not as slow as before.

In general, I've found that this is a fairly reliable way to fix the problem you're having; and, have done it for several accounts at work.  The "**Envelope Index**" file will be recreated; but, it should be a "cleaner" version.

Comment: Thanks Kent. But if Spotlight is indexing the entire computer hard drive, is there a way to simply make Spotlight stop re-indexing constantly?

Comment: Apple's way: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409  And, another way which does the same thing: http://syamsul.net/2012/12/25/how-to-reset-spotlight-indexing-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/   But, even then, the mail folder might be handled differently...